# AdWords Campaign Id

Tags: c#, .net, adsense, google-ads-api

I am new to AdWords and am having trouble using it. Essentially, I need to get the campaign Id of my campaign so that I can use the API to upload images to it. However, it is not very clear where to find it, and the documentation and examples provided by Google are less than stellar. I read somewhere that the campaign id is the value in the querystring with key "__c" but this didn't work.

One way of getting it seems to be to get all the campaigns belonging to a particular user and then filter by name. However, it is unclear how to set up the AdWordsUser instance so that it can connect properly with AdWords.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Conor

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, one common reason for this error is that you don't have the maximumErrorResponseLength key in your App.config. By default, .NET framework truncates an error response to 64K, which is bad, if the response is an xml - you'd end up with a malformed xml. Soap error responses > 64K is common in AdWords API.

As soon as I set this in my web.config, the issue was resolved.